# regExp to cover the entire range of hours

Tags: php, regexp-substr

[image]

I need my regexp to cover every hour range that is below.

```
07:00 - 15:30
16:00 bis 20:30
7:00-15:00
7.00 Uhr 16.30 Uhr
7 - 16.30 Uhr
7 - 16 Uhr
7:30 - 16 Uhr
7:15 Uhr bis 16:30 Uhr
7-16.15 Uhr
```

I need regExp to cover the entire range of hours, each of the following and nothing else

I have a regExp

```
([0-9] | [01]? [0-9] | 2 [0-3]) ((: |. |.) ([0-5] [0-9])?) ( . *?) ([0-9] | [01]? [0-9] | 2 [0-3]) ((: |. |.) ([0-5] [0-9])?)
```

but it doesn't work as much as I would like it to

7:00-15 instead 7:00-15:00
7.00 Uhr 16 instead 7.00 Uhr 16.30 Uhr

Comment: `I have a regExp` ...ok but you forgot the next bit of your post, where you tell us what goes wrong currently, and what you've done so far to try and resolve it. See also [ask]. Also, your picture seems to contain more data than your question. You must provide _all_ relevant code and data _as text_ within your post, so people can easily re-use it to test possible solutions etc. Pictures are for illustration only. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression matches all the entries you listed:

```
^(?<start>(?<starthour>[0-9]+)(?:[:\.](?<startminute>[0-9]+))?)(?:[\s]*(?:[-—]|bis|Uhr)[\s]*)*(?<end>(?<endhour>[0-9]+)(?:[:\.](?<endminute>[0-9]+))?)(?:[\s]*(?:Uhr)[\s]*)?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/48i2aZ/2

I left out capturing "Uhr" and "bis" - I don't speak German but I assume they mean something like hour or between the hours of.